# Toggle pin on Arduino Micro without disrupting operation

Tags: arduino, toggle, microcontroller

I have a code that once it receives a particular input over the serial it will turn 2 pins high, and wait for an interrupt to occur and run its code. I tried using an infinite `loop(while 1)` but the interrupt routine can't get executed when the button is pressed.

I want the outputs `LED` and `BEEP` to toggle after `'C'` is received and until the interrupt occurs.

```
// Declarations before

void loop() {
    while(Serial.available())
    { 
        char data = Serial.read();  
        if(data == 'C')
        {
            digitalWrite(BEEP, 1);
            digitalWrite(LED, 1);
            flag = true;
        }   
    }

// Interrupt routine
```

Comment: Sorry but... Where is the code? it stops at `// Interrupt routine`. Moreover since it is not so long you can post it here, so it will be more clear (and also more useful to the people coming here in, let's say, 10 years ;) )

Comment: Where's the code to init the interrupt to catch the button pulse? Where's the ISR!?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/FKkVi0Qe

Comment: @frarugi87 here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/FKkVi0Qe

Comment: @Paul Bajan. Excuse me, but I forget to ask you about the MCU that you use. What's the MCU?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini in the title he says Arduino Micro, so it should be an Atmega 32u4

Comment: @Paul Bajan. I think the same thing that frarugi87 posted you as answer! have you verified the HW configuration? (pull-up and connection of the button to GND)

Comment: @frarugi, I've intended it as AVR Micro ... ;) ah ah ah ah ah ... :_)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini It is the Arduino micro so Atmega 32u4. I wanted to do the toggle just from software. Once the character from the serial is received I wanted it to start toggling...with no input from the interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on a simulator:

```
#define ITR_PIN 3

volatile boolean start = false;

volatile boolean flag = false;

int LED= 4;

/**
 * This method is called on the interruption raised on the falling front of the PIN2
 * The start flag is used to avoid rebound front. Interruptions are disabled inside the 
 * interrupt vector method.
 * start is reset once it has been processed in the main loop() 
 */
void buttonPressed()
{
  if(flag)
  {
    if (!start)
    {
      start = true;
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  cli();
  pinMode(ITR_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, buttonPressed, FALLING); // Pin 3
  sei();
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop(){

  while(Serial.available())
  { 
    char data = Serial.read();   

    if(data == 'C')
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, 1);
      flag = true;
    } 
  }

  if(flag == true)
    if (start)
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      delay(50);
      start = false;
      flag=false;  
    }
}
```

(it's just a reduced version of yours, I just removed the stepper dependancies and marked flag as volatile). It works with this hardware:

[image: arduino micro sample circuit]

However, I'm pretty sure that you haven't added the pullup to your circuit!

The solution is:

1. add a resistor (e.g. 10 kOhm) between pin 3 and +5V
2. enable the internal pullup

Solution 2 is the preferred one: you just have to change

```
pinMode(ITR_PIN, INPUT);
```

into

```
pinMode(ITR_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

**EDIT:**

According to your comment I think that the behavior should be different:

- Everything is off
- When you receive a C on the serial interface the led starts "blinking"
- When the interrupt is asserted it stops blinking.

I modified the code to achieve this; I slightly reduced the rest of the code (but you can merge it with the previous one)

```
#define ITR_PIN 3

volatile boolean flag = false;

const int blink_period_ms = 500; // Blink period in milliseconds

unsigned long initialBlinkTime;

int LED= 4;

void buttonPressed()
{
  flag = false;
}

void setup()
{
  cli();
  pinMode(ITR_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, buttonPressed, FALLING); // Pin 3
  sei();
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop(){

  while(Serial.available())
  { 
    char data = Serial.read();   

    if(data == 'C')
    {
      if (!flag)
      {
        initialBlinkTime = millis();
        flag = true;
      }
    } 
  }

  if(flag)
  {
    int currentTime = millis() - initialBlinkTime;
    while (currentTime > blink_period_ms) currentTime -= blink_period_ms;

    digitalWrite(LED, currentTime < blink_period_ms/2);
    // Insert here the other instructions
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

Comment: I does not toggle though. It is the same code as I had before just with the interrupt. By toggle I mean that I want it to flash on and off. Otherwise the code works fine. I think I just wasn't clear with what i meant by toggle. I want the LED to flash on and off(so the pin voltage to turn on and off) once the serial is received and to continue doing that until the interrupt is called.

Comment: Edited the answer according to what I understood ;)

Answer (score 0):

When this code receives a 'C' char from the serial the code starts a led flashing for 50 msec on and for 50 msec off, the led flashing stops when the interrupt ITR_PIN is generated (the ISR buttonPressed function will be called!)

```
#define ITR_PIN 3

volatile bool start = false;
bool ledstatus = false;

int LED= 4;

/**
 * This method is called on the interruption raised on the falling front of the PIN2
 * The start flag is used to avoid rebound front. Interruptions are disabled inside the
 * interrupt vector method.
 * start is reset once it has been processed in the main loop()
 */
void buttonPressed()
{
    start=false;
}

void setup()
{
    cli();
    pinMode(ITR_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0, buttonPressed, FALLING); // Pin 3
    sei();
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

    while(Serial.available())
    {
        char data = Serial.read();

        if(data == 'C')
        {
          start = true;
        }
    }

    if (start)
    {
        ledstatus=!ledstatus;
        digitalWrite(LED, (ledstatus)?HIGH:LOW);
        delay(50);
    } else {
        if (ledstatus) {
            ledstatus=false;
            digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
        }
    }        

}
```